# "Return" not working, cannot "exit" a function

Tags: c++, return

I have some functions that need to be called multiple times, as such

```
int i;
i = 10;
while (i > 0)
{
    selectletter(wordArray);
    computerTurn(wordArray);
    printGrid(grid);
    i--;
}
```

The function selectletter works fine, and near the end of that function, it calls another function, "claimword". Claimword runs entirely fine, but at the end of the function, the program crashes when it runs out of context, as opposed to it just moving on to computerTurn as it should as shown above. I looked up on SO how to "exit" a function, and everyone said that "return;" would work fine, even in a void function. However, when I try using return, nothing at all happens, except for anything after the return statement is ignored. Can anyone tell me why the return statement doesn't work?

```
void claimword(Tile grid[7][6], char letter, string wordArray[100])
{
    cout << "Would you like to claim a word? (Y/N)" << endl;
    char chooseinput;
    cin >> chooseinput;
    if ((chooseinput == 'y') || (chooseinput == 'Y'))
    {
    printGrid(grid);
    cout << "Please enter the word you would like to claim." << endl;
    string input;
    cin >> input;
    int inthegrid = 0;
    int errormessage = 0;
    compchecker(grid, input, inthegrid);
    int length;
    if (inthegrid = 1)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
        {
            if (input == wordArray[i])
            {
                if (input.find(letter) != std::string::npos)
                {
                    string strl;
                    strl = wordArray[i];

                    length = strl.length();
                    cout << "You have claimed the word " << strl << endl;
                    wordArray[i] = "/";

                }
                else
                {
                    errormessage = 1;
                }

            }
            else
            {
                ///cout << "Sorry, that word is not in the dictionary." << endl;
                errormessage = 2;
            }
        }
        if (errormessage = 1)
        {
            cout << "Sorry you cannot claim that word." << endl;
        }
        if (errormessage = 2)
        {
            cout << "Sorry, that word is not in the dictionary." << endl;

        }
                    if (length == 3)
                    {
                        human.humanpoints = human.humanpoints + 1;
                        wordsthisturn = wordsthisturn + 1;
                        cout << "You have earned one point!" << endl;
                    }
                    if (length == 4)
                    {
                        human.humanpoints = human.humanpoints + 2;
                        wordsthisturn = wordsthisturn + 2;
                        cout << "You have earned two points!" << endl;
                    }
                    if (length == 5)
                    {
                        human.humanpoints = human.humanpoints + 4;
                        wordsthisturn = wordsthisturn + 4;
                        cout << "You have earned four points!" << endl;
                    }
                    if (length == 6)
                    {
                        human.humanpoints = human.humanpoints + 8;
                        wordsthisturn = wordsthisturn + 8;
                        cout << "You have earned eight points!" << endl;
                    }
                    if (length == 7)
                    {
                        human.humanpoints = human.humanpoints + 16;
                        wordsthisturn = wordsthisturn + 16;
                        cout << "You have earned sixteen points!" << endl;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cout << "Your word was too small to claim any points." << endl;
                    }

    }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "End of Player Turn." << endl;
        //return;
    }
    cout <<"Test1";
    return;
    cout <<"Test2";

}
```

Regardless of the input I give it (y/n and such), "Test1" displays, but "Test2" doesn't. My theory is that the program doesn't return all the way, or I'm just simply not using it right.

EDIT:

With an edited statement in the main function,

```
        selectletter(wordArray);
        cout << "test11";
        computerTurn(wordArray);
```

What should happen is that the selectletter function should be called. The selectletter function, at the end of it, calls another function, claimWord. claimWord is posted above. At the end of the function, it should end. There should be nothing left for it to do, and after all those if/elses regarding points, and even if no points are scored, or anything in the function happens, the function should end. The program should then display "test11", but it does not.

EDIT2:

```
void selectletter(string wordArray[100])
{
    cout << endl;
    cout << "REMAINING LETTERS:" << endl;
    cout << human.humanletters << endl;
    cout << "Select a letter.";
    int length;
    length = human.humanletters.size();
    char input;
    cin >> input;
    int column;
    int row = 7;
    int cinput;
    //mght have to change since 0 is the first val
    cout << "What column would you like to drop that in? (1-7)";
    cin >> cinput;
    column = cinput - 1;
    //cout << "Test1";
    while (row > 0)
    {
    if (grid[row-1][column].active == true)
    {
        row--;
        //cout << "Test3";
    }
    else
        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {

        if(human.humanletters[i] == input)
        {
            //cout << "Test5";
            human.humanletters.erase(std::remove(human.humanletters.begin(), human.humanletters.end(), input), human.humanletters.end());
            grid[row-1][column].letter = input;
            grid[row-1][column].active = true;
            cout << endl;
            //cout << "Test6";
            claimword(grid, input, wordArray);
            //this removes ALL instances of the letter, however
        }
        break;
        //need to add something for if the letter is not in the string
    //}
        //row = 9999;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `return` will return from whatever function it is called from. It won't go multiple layers if that is what you are trying to do.

Comment: You're not using it right.

Comment: "However, when I try using return, nothing at all happens, except for anything after the return statement is ignored" - what else do you expect to happen? That sounds exactly like exiting the function to me.

Comment: Debugging confusion because something raised an exception?

Comment: In all of the questions regarding using "return" to exit a function, it seemed like simply putting return there would exit the function. I just want the function to end, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: You said "anything after the return statement is ignored". How is that different from the function ending?

Comment: The function may "end", but the statement after the one that called that function never initiates. I assume that since the computerPlayer function (that goes directly after the previous function, which I want to 'end'), does not start up, (but has shown to start up completely fine without the other function in front of it), then the function has not truly ended. I'm sorry if this isn't the right way to word it, but I am not familiar with the return statement.

Comment: You'll have to post the expected behavior of your code, the observed behavior, and the relevant code. There's nothing wrong with the code you posted here.

Comment: Alright, I am editing the main question now. Thank you.

Comment: You didn't edit in the observed behavior, you just said that it doesn't work. What happens instead of putting "test11" to standard out?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. Everything that the function is supposed to do works, it asks me if I want to claim a word, asks me what word I want to claim, everything it should do except for end. The program just stops until I hit x. "test11" is not displayed.

Comment: you probably have an infinite loop somewhere. Somewhere in the code you haven't posted yet.

Comment: Try adding an `<< endl;` after the `cout << test11`. The standard output is buffered and the text might be in the buffer waiting to be flushed.

Comment: Tried that, it didn't change anything.

Comment: Posting the function that calls claimWord. I don't understand how that would necessarily influence the claimWord function to have an infinite loop, but I'll post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your while loop has the condition `while (row > 0)`, and you only decrement `row` when `(grid[row-1][column].active == true)`. If that ever evaluates to `false`, you won't decrement `row` and your program runs forever.

Perhaps your `break;` was meant to break out of the while loop, but all it will do is break out of the for loop. A `break` statement breaks out of the nearest enclosing loop/switch block.

Comment: I'm working on fixing that right now, but how would that affect the claimword function? The program is able to run the claimword function (where the problem perceivably is) out of that loop

Comment: Ok, I have no idea how it worked, but I tried adding in a statement to make row a negative number after claimword is called, and it works now. Thank you!

Comment: The problem was never with claimWorld. Perhaps the output of your program made it seem like that, but that wasn't the case.

Answer (score 1):

> Regardless of the input I give it (y/n and such), "Test1" displays, but "Test2" doesn't.

That is what it is *supposed* to do.  You called `return` after displaying `Test1` and before displaying `Test2`, so the latter was skipped.  `return` is an *immediate* return to the function that called the current function.